# Vagrant SSH Connection refused - correct syntax?

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I created a user using 'adduser' on a Ubuntu 18 virtual machine that I ssh'd into using Vagrant. I am now trying to ssh into the server using the user credentials I created. I keep getting connection refused. I believe it is my syntax that is causing this so what is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add here your "code"
but `Connection refused` can be caused by several reasons.
SSH service is down, Wrong credentials, port is closed, wrong permissions or don't have permissions to connect at all.
Take a look [here](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/ssh-connection-refused/) and try to solve it.